# I am using appium for automation testing

Tags: appium

How to move seekbar in IOS
I am using Appium for Automation testing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V8X3.png)

I have red marked for that WebElement in above image
I am taking Xpath for that Webelement
I am using below Function

```
WebElement sliderMove = MobileUtils.getMobElement(fieldObjects, testCase, "sleepBrightnessSliderBar");
int xAxisStartPoint = sliderMove.getLocation().getX();
int xAxisEndPoint = xAxisStartPoint + sliderMove.getSize().getWidth();
int yAxis = sliderMove.getLocation().getY();

TouchAction act = new TouchAction(testCase.getDriver());
TouchAction sliderChk = act.longPress(xAxisStartPoint,yAxis).moveTo(xAxisEndPoint-1,yAxis).release().perform();
```

the value of **sliderChk** is not coming null but its not moving that slider to any position
the value of
 xAxisStartPoint =68  xAxisEndPoint =307  yAxis =  160
seekbar can be moved by 10% only
there is five slots i.e 0% 10% 20% 30% 40% 50%
if current value is 10% then i have to move by 10% only i.e to 20% 
how to control seekbar to particular position, if it is moving

Answer (score 0):

The values on sliders lies between 0 to 1 as per Appium. So you have to write the code as below.

```
driver.findElementByClassName("<SliderClassName>").sendKeys("0.6");
```

The above code moves the slider position to 60% on seek bar.

Comment: I think in  IOS findElementByClassName is not present. It is present in Android. Let me share one image.

Comment: tap on below link to get the screen shot of slider bar . if you see the attributes for IOS there is no class attribute present.         so how to move slider ? I am taking xpath for IOS as well as i have uses name attribute also but it is not moving to a particular position.                                https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=89a22ab1ad&view=att&th=152120ae52915be4&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_ij1gacna0&zw

Comment: findElementByClassName will be available if you initialize the driver as   AppiumDriver driver = new IOSDriver("URL",caps);  I believe you are using webDriver instead of AppiumDriver. That is not a problem.    If you have XPath then XPath or name use name. just replace the ClassName in my code with Xpath/name.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("<name_Of_Slider>")).sendKeys("0.6");                 or                                                                                                                                                                 driver.findElement(By.XPath("<XPath_of_Slider>")).sendKeys("1.0");

Comment: AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = testCase.getDriver();  driver.findElementByXPath("sleepBrightnessSliderBar").sendKeys("0.6");      I have used above line to move slider byXPath and byName also but it is giving me parser error

Comment: sleepBrightnessSliderBar is not XPath for sure. About Name could pls share appium inspector view screenshot. So that we can come to a conclusion. Actually for all sliders classname is UIASlider. try with that as driver.findElement(By.className("UIASlider")).sendKeys("0.6");

Comment: Hey guys, I'm also facing an issue related to that. Can you guys look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757776/how-to-move-android-seekbar-backward-in-selenium/62758237?noredirect=1#comment111002727_62758237 and help me if you know the solution ?