# How to move Android Seekbar forward/backward in selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, android-seekbar

I have a `SeekBar` of an Android video player library, and I want to move it using selenium in forward/backward direction:

[image]

I want to move this `SeekBar` in forward/backward direction but I'm not able to do that. I am trying to move forward as:

```
 MobileElement seekBar = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.SeekBar");
        seekBar.click();
// get start co-ordinate of seekbar
    int start = seekBar.getLocation().getX();
    // Get width of seekbar
    int end = seekBar.getSize().getWidth();
    // get location of seekbar vertically
    int y = seekBar.getLocation().getY();

    // Select till which position you want to move the seekbar
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

    // Move it 40%
    int moveTo = (int) (end * 0.4);
    action.longPress(start, y).moveTo(moveTo, y).release().perform();
```

But its always coming to a certain point whether I change value for `end`  and  `start` or not. The code I'm trying to move backward is as:

```
public void moveSeekBarBackward(MobileElement seekBar, AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver) {
    // get start co-ordinate of seekbar
    seekBar.click();
    int start = seekBar.getLocation().getX();

    // Get width of seekbar
    int end = seekBar.getSize().getWidth();
    // get location of seekbar vertically
    int y = seekBar.getLocation().getY();

    // Select till which position you want to move the seekbar
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

    // Move it 20%
    int moveTo = (int) (end * 0.2);
    action.longPress(start, y).moveTo(moveTo, y).release().perform();
}
```

Above code is starting the video from the same place where it starts after making it forward.
Please let me know if you the correct solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the second solution but use there long-press instead of the press

```
action.longpress(start, y).moveTo(moveTo, y).release().perform();
```

Comment: Yeah, tried but it also doesn't work. And also there is no error.

Comment: I'm able to move forward now but not backward. Can you see my snippet now and let me know?

Comment: Then you should write new method for moving back, because your cursor actual location is in 40%, you should get the new x and y for seekbar and move to direction less than 40%

Comment: I have updated my question with the updated code. Please check and correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: No, I think it should work, try to move backward with the press instead of long press and see the result, maybe it will work

Comment: Sorry there is no change.